# Inline Height Being Added To Div

Tags: javascript, css, inline

When I view a certain wordpress page in a browser and firebug it, it appears that there is an lnline style being added to my div.

I have written it like such...

```
<div class="menuCol-left">
<div class="menuitem">
<h3>Buffalo Boneless Wing Dip</h3>
<p>If you like boneless wings then this dip is for you! A blend of three cheeses, zesty boneless wings, Cajun pepper sauce and our special seasonings all baked together to create this unique dip. Served with tortilla chips and pita points for diggin in.</p>
<p>~ <b>$10.99</b></p>
</div>
</div>
```

But when I pull it up in Inspect Element it show like so.. (starts to show where its happening)

```
<div class="menuCol-left">
*********<div class="menuitem" style="height:168px">*********
<h3>Buffalo Boneless Wing Dip</h3>
<p>If you like boneless wings then this dip is for you! A blend of three cheeses, zesty boneless wings, Cajun pepper sauce and our special seasonings all baked together to create this unique dip. Served with tortilla chips and pita points for diggin in.</p>
<p>~ <b>$10.99</b></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Could this be a javascript issue? I've tried adding min-height:0 !important; 
It says nothing in the CSS file about height for .menuitem and there is nothing in the markup about it. I'm perplexed.

Comment: Do you use any plugin for your menu?

Comment: It looks like a Javascript problem, but without the full code I could only guess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some javascript code is setting the height of the element. Try searching for `.menuitem` to know, which script does it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Brackets, Dreamweaver, Sublime or antoher editor that can search across all files. Search for "#menuitem" and "menuitem", without the colons. There may be a PHP tag adding stuff there, or a JavaScript script calling this id and adding this parameter to the element somewhere in your files.